# Table of contents inside an included PDF

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages, include, links

I've got some problem with LaTeX right now, well to be honest it's not really a problem and I'm not even sure that it is possible but I would like to be able to do it.

Basically, here is my LaTeX :

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A ~~Included}
\includepdf [pages  = -] {included.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Let say that `Content.tex` contains `included.pdf`. So I have links in the table of contents inside `Content.tex` and that's good.

But I have also a table of contents inside `included.pdf` but when I used `\includepdf`, the link inside this `included.pdf`->tableOfContents doesn't work anymore...

If one of you has any idea how to make theses links work again, because I looked inside the `\includepdf` documentation, and I didn't find what I wanted... :/

Thanks in advance for your help,

Best regards

Comment: As far as I know included `.pdf` are `.flat`, i.e. all hyperlink information is lost

Comment: 1. Can you explain what kind of links those are? I.e. how did you make them? 2. It's a bad idea to include a PDF if the PDF is a compiled latex document. Rather use `\include` or `\input` on the `included.tex` and your links will work. 3. Your document surely contains a `\documentclass` at the beginning, can you include it?

Comment: @Turion: The OP does not necessarily have the LaTeX sources at hand, so even if the included `.pdf` has been generated from LaTeX sources there might be problems

Comment: You can use the [`pax`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax) package to ensure that links in included PDFs remain. I wrote how to do this for Windows/MikTeX on my personal website: http://bryanwweber.com/writing/personal/2014/04/13/use-pax-to-extract-and-include-links-from-external-pdf-files-in-latex-on-windows/

Comment: indeed, I don't have the source of the included .pdf unfortunatelly...

But it was a LaTeX source code before, and the PDF itself (when opened with Adobe Reader for example) has still links (for the Table of Contents for instance).